# How to check checkbox when a-tag is clicked in each table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with an older version of jquery. My current code only works on the first line of my table. If I switch it to a class instead of an ID, it checks every row. I need it to work individually on each row.

Jquery Code:

```
$('#enableCheckbox').click(function(){
    $('#checkbox').attr("checked", true);
})
```

HTML:

```
<td><a href="pdfview.cfm?id=#hardwareid#" target="_blank" id="enableCheckbox">Create</a></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"></td>
```

Comment: Whenever you would like to ask for help, go to JSFiddle and create a small snippet that includes the code that is buggy. To add JQuery, you would have to add a CDN url in that fiddle under `External Resources` on the left side. Go to https://jsfiddle.net/. To help you, we would have to copy/paste the code to our own environment and execute it, so adding a JSFiddle URL makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check checkbox on every a tag click so don't give id to a tag because its work for first id only.

Please see below code, I think it's will be help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table tr td a").click(function (e) {
          $(this).parent().next().find('input').attr("checked", true);
  //If you want to check and uncheck on click then follow below code
  //$(this).parent().next().find('input').attr("checked", !$(this).parent().next().find('input').attr("checked"));
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank">Create</a></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank">Create</a></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

ids must be unique on a table, so you cannot use the same id for each row of the table as most browsers will only return the very first element that has the id. (That is the reason that you are only getting the first row of the table).

What you can do, is you can set your event listener for a class like you mentioned, but also have a unique data element for the table row.

Or if you don't have another input in the subsequent table cell you could use some code like this:

```
$('.enableCheckbox').on("click", function(event){
   var $input = $(event.target).parent().find("input");
   $input.prop("checked", true);
});
```